# WebAPI Conflicting routes for nested resources

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am developing an API in WebAPI (First One) and i am having some issues with the specifity of routes and mapping them to the actions in my controllers for nested resources.

I have the following resources:

1. Projects (root level resource)
2. Sites (root level resource)
3. Zones (Sub resource of Site)

so i can have some funky nesting like:

- /api/projects/1/sites
- /api/projects/1/sites/assigned
- /api/sites/1/zones
- /api/sites/1/zones/1

The problem i am having is with some of the end points, specifically the site/zone ones.  I currently have two Get methods, one to get zones by siteId and page, and the other to get a Zone by Id (Code below is messy, i needs a refactor but just trying to get my head round WebAPI).

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        var zone = (from z in _repo
                    where z.Id == id
                    select z)
            .SingleOrDefault()
            .ToRepresentation<Zone, ZoneRepresentation>();

        resp.Content = new ObjectContent<ZoneRepresentation>(zone, new JsonHalMediaTypeFormatter());

        return resp;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage GetByPage(int siteId, int page = DefaultPage, int pageSize = PageSize)
    {
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        //TODO: Make sure access to project is checked....

        var pagingInfo = (from z in _repo
                          where z.Site.Id == siteId
                          select z)
                          .GetPagingInfo<Zone>(pageSize);

        if (pagingInfo.TotalRecords > 0)
        {
            if (page > pagingInfo.TotalPages)
            {
                resp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
            }

            var zones = (from z in _repo.Include("Site")
                         where z.Site.Id == siteId
                         select z)
                         .OrderBy(z => z.Name)
                         .Paging(page, DefaultPage, pageSize)
                         .ToPagedRepresentation<Zone, ZoneListRepresentation>(pagingInfo.TotalRecords, pagingInfo.TotalPages, page, new Link("Zones", "/sites/" + siteId.ToString() + "/zones?page={page}"));

            resp.Content = new ObjectContent<ZoneListRepresentation>(zones, new JsonHalMediaTypeFormatter());
        }
        else
        {
            resp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
            throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
        }

        return resp;
    }
```

With no additional routes specified these do not work, so trying to access:

- /api/sites/1/zones
- /api/sites/1/zones/1

will result in 404's.

To get the first route to work i add the following route configuration (i am sure there is a more general approach but just want to get this working as simply as possible):

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "SiteZonesApiRoute",
            routeTemplate: "api/sites/{siteId}/zones/{id}",
            defaults: new { Controller = "Zones", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Which works for the first link, but passing in an ID i get:

```
ExceptionMessage":"Multiple actions were found that match the request:     
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Get(Int32) on type API.Controllers.ZonesController
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage GetByPage(Int32, Int32, Int32) on type 
API.Controllers.ZonesController
```

Ok fine, i have two GET methods, although one accepts one int and the other three, so i am little confused as to why it's getting muddled but i think that is down to routes an all being a new concept.  What i then do is add a very specific route handler for the ID type and pointing to the specific action method:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
             name: "ZoneByIdApiRoute",
             routeTemplate: "api/sites/{siteId}/zones/{id}",
             defaults: new { Controller = "Zones", action="Get" }
         );
```

Great, that worked......Well not really as for some reason, the very specific route completely breaks the PUT method, with always now returns a 405 and i can't get around it.

Is it clear to see what i have done wrong here?  I could create more controllers but that seems like passing the problem around and i am completely stuck.

Comment: can you post your entire route config?

Comment: Hi Rob the only thing missing is the default route outlined by WebAPI

Comment: What does your PUT method look like?

Comment: away from the machine now, will add the put message in the morning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the signatures of your controller methods matches your routes it should work.

You write that you want the following routes to be matched:

- /api/sites/1/zones
- /api/sites/1/zones/1

I.e siteId is a mandatory parameter and id (zoneId) is optional.

This means you should have a controller method named Get or GetSomething that takes siteId and id as parameters. Id may be optional, or you could have another method that only has siteId as parameters.

E.g. this would work:

```
    public class ZonesController : ApiController
    {
    // /api/sites/1/zones/1
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int siteId, int id)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.OK, string.Format("siteId: {0}. Id: {1}", siteId, id));
    }

    // /api/sites/1/zones?page=12&pageSize=30
    public HttpResponseMessage GetByPage(int siteId, int page = 0, int pageSize = 10)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.OK, string.Format("siteId: {0}. page: {1}", siteId, page));
    }
}
```

Route config:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "SiteZonesApiRoute",
        routeTemplate: "api/sites/{siteId}/zones/{id}",
        defaults: new { Controller = "Zones", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: i was wondering if siteId was required but as it isn't really used in the single zone get method it felt a bit hacky, will test in the morning

Comment: This is the answer, feels really icky to have something in a route that does nothing in a method but either i make my controllers more granular or work this way i suppose.  Need to read up more on routes!